# How to persist selected value for Material UI Autocomplete on mount?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form

I made an Autocomplete component using react-hook-form and Material UI's autocomplete. The form is a wizard-form (multistep form) so when I switch steps the component unmounts. Here's the code

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Autocomplete as MuiAutcomplete} from "@mui/material";
import {useFormContext} from "react-hook-form";

interface props {
    name: string,
    options?: string[],
    getOptions?: (value: string) => { // For fetching values while typing
        label: string,
        id: number
    }[],
};

const Autocomplete = ({name, options=[], getOptions}: props) => {
    const [autcompleteValues, setAutocompleteValues] = useState<any[]>([]);
    const {watch, register} = useFormContext();

    const watchValue = watch(name);
    useEffect(() => {
        if (getOptions) {
           setAutocompleteValues(getOptions(watchValue));
        }
    }, [watchValue]);

    return (
        <MuiAutcomplete
        options={getOptions? autcompleteValues: options}
        renderInput={({InputProps, inputProps}) => (
                <div ref={InputProps.ref}>
                    <input type="text" {...inputProps} className="bg-transparent outline-none p-1"/>
                </div>
            )
        }
        getOptionLabel={option => option.label || option}
        {...register(name)}
        />
    )
}

export default Autocomplete
```

The component works just fine but when I switch steps and go back to it, the input field is empty. The value is still registered but it doesn't show in the input box. How can I make it so the value gets saved even if I switch pages?

Comment: the value of Autocomplete is not controlled. Assuming `watchValue` is the value that is supposed to be binded to the control, try adding this to the component's props `value={watchValue}`

Comment: @MujeebQureshi I tried that but then it won't let me edit it since it inforfes the watched value

Comment: Okay so since you are using react-hook-form, the way to do it is to register the control something like this `{...register(name)}`. This is the link to the library docs: https://react-hook-form.com/api/useformcontext

Comment: @MujeebQureshi But isn't MUI controlled. Does it also work with uncontrolled inputs?

Comment: Not by default. When you bind the value with a state variable and fix up a onChange handler, that when it becomes controlled

Comment: @MujeebQureshi I edited the question using `register` but now it doesn't register. The `required` error message shows up meaning that it's not saving the value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if you figured it out but make the following changes on your `Autocomplete` component like this:

```
const { watch, register, setValue, getValues } = useFormContext();
```

get the `getValues` and `setValue` function from `useFormContext`

Have them placed like this in Mui control (remove register altogether):

```
<MuiAutcomplete
  options={getOptions ? autcompleteValues : options}
  renderInput={({ InputProps, inputProps }) => (
    <div ref={InputProps.ref}>
      <input
        type="text"
        {...inputProps}
        className="bg-transparent outline-none p-1"
      />
    </div>
  )}
  value={getValues(name)}
  onChange={(e, v) => {
    console.log("Mui change", v);
    setValue(name, v);
  }}
  getOptionLabel={(option) => option.label || option}
/>
```

Comment: I have scafolded a minimum example of your use case here, check it out: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-forked-gg39mz?file=/src/App.tsx